# FIX TD colspan with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="details">Some Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can i be able to fix the colspan to normal table column so the column will be divided equally..? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's the first way that came to mind:

```
$("td[colspan]").each(function() {   // find all tds that have a colspan specified
    var $td = $(this),
        cols = +$td.attr("colspan"); // get the value

    $td.attr("colspan",1);           // set the cell to have colspan 1
    for (var i = 1; i < cols; i++)   // add as many clones of the current cell
       $td.after($td.clone());       // as needed to replace the original colspan
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vpw8j/